# Creating insert into mysql script

Tags: python, mysql, cursor

I am trying to create a `.sql` file containing insert statement from a table. Basically, I get the data from one table, do some modification, then create insert statement from a list of dict and write it to a file. However, the issue is with the text field. The values are not escaped. Is there any utility/helper function that can help me get the insert statement with the handling of escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `text.replace('', '')` to escape characters that do not fit in the SQL query.